# java mail service

Tags: java

is it possible to send newsletter from my site to my clients yahoo,rediff mail accounts

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

Links:

- http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/javaserver-pages/how-to-send-e-mail-through-jsp.html
- http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1163

Comment: FROM WHERE I HAVE TO COLLECT TLD FILES.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @thelost - hehe, exactly the same as I had it. :P

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is.

http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html